# Arguments in button command to change global variable value python tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, global-variables

I'm trying to get a set of buttons that will change the value of my global variable "y". I'm pretty new to python, and am very new to tkinter. I have tried using lambda and solutions in similar questions haven't seemed to fix the issue.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


master=Tk()

def assignint(value):
    global y
    y = value

y= StringVar()

frame = Frame(master)
frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
for i in range(2):
    Grid.rowconfigure(master,i,weight=1)
for i in range(4):
    Grid.columnconfigure(master,i,weight=1)

Button1 = Button(master,text='Fault1',command= lambda: assignint(0))
Button1.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)


Button2 = Button(master,text='Fault2',command= lambda: assignint(1))
Button2.grid(row=1, column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W)


Button3 = Button(master,text='Fault3',command= lambda: assignint(2))
Button3.grid(row=1, column=2,sticky=N+S+E+W)


Button4= Button(master,text='Fault4',command= lambda: assignint(3))
Button4.grid(row=1, column=3,sticky=N+S+E+W)

if y.get()!='':
    print('The value of y is:', y.get())

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your condition for print statement runs before the condition has a chance to be true.

Comment: Just tried removing the if statement and the issue is still the same, the value of y remains blank

Comment: `y` is blank because `print` runs before you have a chance to change it's value. As in It runs just before your GUI is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `set` method when changing a `StringVar`'s value.

as in replace:

```
y = value
```

with:

```
y.set(value)
```

Comment: That's made no difference still not getting the print statement working.

Comment: @Jkind9 Try to put it in another button for a later calling. In its current state it runs only once and that's when the condition is False.

Comment: @Jkind9 No problem. I'd also take a look at tkinter [frequent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter?sort=frequent).